# Bad Headphone Connector Wiring Issues - What Could Be Wrong?

Tags: audio, connector, sound, fault, headphones

I am trying to repair a headphone cable with a splice. The audio sounds really bad after the repair. I can hear instruments, but not the vocals. Also, the playback is mono, same sound on both sides.

If I short Left to Right, the audio gets quiet, but still sounds bad. If I short Left to Common, *or* Right to Common, the sound quality returns to normal, but audio playback is still mono. Does this mean there is a open connection on common, *and* a short between Left and Right? Or is some other fault possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe could be explained with simply an open common, assuming that you channel to common short test is **before** the open, i. e. at the source.

With the open common, you have the phones in series with the ends connected between L and R. You are hearing the **difference** between the channels. This cancels out "centered" sound.

By shorting common to Left, **at the source**, you'd end up with the phones in series between Right and common. You'd hear only Right, being fed to both sides, though out of phase between sides.

Answer (score 0):

This matches the case of the missing common ground so that common mode gets nulled by the differential between Left and right.

Fix the missing ground.